# jQuery audio volume per unique instance

Tags: php, jquery, dynamic

I have a series of html5 audio player (dynamically generated), that I adjust the volume with a jquery slider. The problem  I am having is that moving one slider changes the audio output volume for all. It does not change each instances audio setting. I wonder if anyone could help me with this, so that it only effect the audio player it is tied to.

```
//volume audio
$(document).ready(function () {
    audio = $("#<?php echo $track_id; ?>").get(0);
    audio.volume =<?php echo $trackVolume; ?>;
    $("#volumeAudio<?php echo $track_id; ?>").each(function() {
        $( this ).empty().slider({
            value: <?php echo $trackVolume; ?>,
            orientation: "horizontal",
            range: "min",
            max: 1,
            step: 0.1,
            animate: true,
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                audio.volume = ui.value;
                $.post( 
                    "processForms/process_presentation.php", { presentationProcessing: 'updateAudioSliderVolume', presentationId: <?php echo $pres_id; ?>, trackID: <?php echo $track_id; ?>, sliderValueVolume: ui.value}
                );
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: Are you calling `each()` on a list of item that should contain only one object `#volumeAudio<?php echo $track_id; ?>`? ID should be unique.

Comment: In that context it seems $track_id would be concatenated in order to make it a unique ID.

Comment: this #volumeAudio<?php echo $track_id; ?> is unique per each audio player. Should  I drop the each? If so can you rewrite my script so I can see how to do that?

Comment: it seems that it is this line "audio.volume = ui.value;" that is causing the error. It changes the volume overall of all tracks playing. It does not overwrite what they have as there saved setting, just the instance. It may have been also helpful to note, that if I have five pieces of audio and one ends, I have code that plays the next audio piece in line. Do you notice somewhere that "audio.volume = ui.value;" is not unique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
audio.volume = ui.value;
```

To

```
$("#<?php echo $track_id; ?>").get(0).volume = ui.value;
```